# Does Craft CMS support these features?

Tags: performance, craft-features, responsive-images, seo

I am evaluating different CMS. I need to know if Craft CMS supports these features:

1. Preview function for different devices, screen sizes and screen configurations(portrait/landscape)
2. Is it possible to publish only a subset of my website?
3. Is lazy loading supported? E.g. loading images on scrollto?
4. Does a frontend created with Craft CMS use much .js code? Can I minimize the amount of .js code (for performance reasons)?
5. Is mobile first approach supported?
6. Are URLs SEO-friendly?
7. Can I integrate Onsite-Banners from external Ad servers?
8. Does the cms contain Digital Asset Management?
9. Which media file types are supported?
10. Is there any REST API provided?
11. Does the CMS internal search engine support synonyms and how about the error tolerance?
12. Can I login to the CMS on mobile devices? Do I have good usability when doing so?
13. Do I upload high resolution images and later on these are generated and maybe compressed for target devices?

Comment: Are you looking for a turn-key solution? This CMS (others, correct me if I am wrong) targets web design professionals to integrate a CMS into client sites, allowing for a lot of customization, whether thru templating the page to fit your needs or integrating professional and/or custom plugin solutions. Download a copy and test it out, try this out https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager and join the craft slack group and have a further dialogue.

Comment: VTC per the reasoning [outlined here...](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/a/94/45) I highly encourage you to ask this question on [Craft Slack](https://craftcms.com/community#slack) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Preview function for different devices, screen sizes and screen
>   configurations(portrait/landscape)

Yes it has live preview. However this isn't per device. You can open the entry with a secret url and then user your browser tools to check different devices

> Is it possible to publish only a subset of my website?

Yes, each entry can be turned on or off

> Is lazy loading supported? E.g. loading images on scrollto? Does a
>   frontend created with Craft CMS use much .js code? Can I minimize the
>   amount of .js code (for performance reasons)? Is mobile first approach
>   supported? Are URLs SEO-friendly?

Yes, it's all how you code it. You can do whatever you want. Craft makes no assumptions or requirements

> Can I integrate Onsite-Banners from external Ad servers?

Yes code as you want

> Does the cms contain Digital Asset Management? Which media file types
>   are supported?

Yes, full list [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#restricting-allowed-file-types):

> Is there any REST API provided? Does the CMS internal search engine
>   support synonyms and how about the error tolerance?

I'm not sure

> Can I login to the CMS on mobile devices? Do I have good usability
>   when doing so?

Yes you do. I've done this myself and it was easy to move around

> Do I upload high resolution images and later on these are generated
>   and maybe compressed for target devices?

Yes you can and then you can set transforms to crop/resize/compress as you want. Targetting per device that all depends on your html.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know? Are you part of the developer team? Or do you just have your own experience with Craft CMS?

Comment: Just my experience using it. I have no experience with REST API so I said not sure. but all my other answers are based on my experience.

Comment: Following up on number 4 and key to understanding what Craft does. Craft does not come with a frontend. No templates are provided, and there are no sites(yet) offering downloadable templates. You create your own html, js, css etc. and tie it into the backend using Craft's templating code.

Comment: @CreateSean Great response, but the answer about the js part might imply Craft supplies some sort of front end.

Comment: Regarding #11: in my experience, the built-in search feature is a little hit-or-miss (but all MySQL-based CMSs are lacking in this area). It supports partial matches and operators but not synonyms. Depending on your requirements you may need to use a third-party service like Google's for example.